# PHP $_FILES empty, fetch formdata

Tags: php, fetch, multipartform-data

I am trying to upload files using web fetch api and PHP. But for some reason the files are not being captured (or sent?) from the web browser to the server. I can still send files with curl though.

```
async function send_files(url, files) { // files = [File(), File(), ...], url = localhost
    const formData = new FormData()
    for (const file of files) {
        formData.append('files[]', file)
    }
    var result = await fetch(url, {
        method: 'POST',
        cors: 'same-origin',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
        },
        body: formData
    })
    return await result.json()
}
```

And in *PHP* if I `print_r($_FILES)` it returns an empty array. Now I know that uploading is working as curl confirms this:

```sh
curl -k -X POST -c ... -b ... -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" -F "files[]=@file1" -F "files[]=@file2" ... https://localhost
```

The request payload in the networking tab in my web shows:

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="files[]"; filename="file1"
Content-Type: text/plain


------WebKitFormBoundaryXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="files[]"; filename="file2"
Content-Type: text/plain


------WebKitFormBoundaryXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX--
```

The networking tab also shows I am only sending 372 B of info to the server, and the combined size of the two files are 941 B. I am not getting any errors either on front end or back end.

Comment: How are you calling that `send_files` function, where does the content of the `files` parameter come from?

Comment: The `send_files` is called in other `async function`s with `await send_json(...)`, then `data.json()` as all my responses are json formatted. The files array is filled with `File()` objects. This array is filled with an input type file that is captured with javascript and placed into an array. with `files = [...files, ...event.target.files]`. Along side that I have a drag and drop file that does `files = [...files, ...event.dataTransfer.files]`.

Comment: For some reason it’s behaving as if the Content-Type was `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` - if a form was submitted that way, only the file _names_ of file input fields gets submitted.

Comment: I even tried it with plain html input and form submit setup with multipart/form-data and it is sending the same payload.

Answer (score 3):

I managed to solve the problem, but honestly it makes no sense to me, confirmed with both firefox and brave browser (thought it might be browser related, its not).

Simply, I needed to remove the headers...

So, the call looks like:

```
async function send_files(url, files) { // files = [File(), File(), ...], url = localhost
    const formData = new FormData()
    for (const file of files) {
        formData.append('files[]', file)
    }
    var result = await fetch(url, {
        method: 'POST',
        cors: 'same-origin',
        //headers: {   REMOVED
        //    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
        //},
        body: formData
    })
    return await result.json()
}
```

I really do not understand why, but from what I saw it seems setting the header changes something in the form data that prevents the data from uploading correctly. Even though I believe that having the header not set it should default to 'application/x-www-url-encoded'.